# How can I allow only admins to post to my Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I have a Facebook group and many of the members use the group to post adverts. I want to approve their posts before they shows publicly on the group.

How can I make their post go through approval before it shows and also give my admins the power to post without their post going through approval?

Answer (score 2):

Yes obviously you can do this. 
Goto group setting and find "Posting Permissions and Post Approval".

Just check the box of **POST APPROVAL**

[image]